# Filter images by 'current page' nid

Tags: views

I have a view with multiple fields:

Nid
Title
Content
Image

On my page, I use the nid as a selector ( I have a button elsewhere on the page tied to it) to open my content without going to another page. The images are also loaded. Only problem I have is that I need to find a way to ensure that only the images for the view row's [nid] are being output, rather than all of them. The [nid]  filter requires a hard value and I'm looking more for a "current page" ish kind of thing.

Basicaly, I want to load only the images that have the same nid as the content being displayed in each row.

How would I set up a filter for this?

Comment: did you try contextual filter?

Answer (score 1):

- Edit your view
- Create Block View
- Add Contextual Filter
  [image]
- Add Content:Nid
  [image]
- In settings choose : Content Id from URL
  [image]
- Enable your block in your node pages where you would like to display images

Comment: I tried this method, but it didn't work on this particular view (probably because all the content is output on the same page) Whenever I use this contextual filter, I get no image output at all.


My page structure is as follows:


<Set of links to open content that is hidden below> 


<Content 1>
Text
Images

<Content 2>
Text
Images


By clicking the links, the corresponding content slides open (jquery with NID matching). Feeding in the Content ID from URL would provide the View with just the NID of the actual View page right?

Comment: Is there such a thing as 'content id from field' perhaps?

Comment: Can you add that js as a gist or pastebin? It will make it easier to understand your question.